# How to access a dll with c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have this code in VB from an older application that uses a dll to search a database. Could you please tell me how can I do it in c#.

Pseek is the dll

```
Dim SeekForm As New PSeek.cSeek
            Dim redRow As mscomctl.ListItem
            Dim succ As Long
            Try
                redRow = Nothing
                succ = SeekForm.CallSeekForm(My.Settings.PSeekConnectionString, "SELECT id,naziv,adresa,broj,vlez,stan,mesto from vSifrarnik where Firmaid = " & My.Settings.curFirma & " and Siftipid=" & SifTipIDUltraCombo.Value, "id,naziv,adresa,broj,vlez,stan,mesto", redRow, 1, , True, False)
                If Not (redRow) Is Nothing Then
                    SifraIDUltraTextEditor.Text = redRow.Text
                    SifraIDUltraTextEditor.Focus()
                End If
            Catch ex As System.Exception
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Comment: `Pseek is the dll` Pseek is **not** the dll, its a class probably contained in the dll. As long as you include the reference to the dll in your project, you can use that class in you C# project

Answer (score 0):

add the dll file, by right click on your project, then add reference and selecting the dll file. Then in your code type

```
using LibraryName;
```

Comment: I did that, but I can't seem to make it do the same action that this VB code does, could you please 'translate the VB code to C#'?